# WAMP - Zend Framework - PHP XDEBUG On By Default?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, wampserver

I'm trying to start a projet and for some reason when I use Doctrine2 and make a database insert, by default I seem to get XDEBUG inserting the following into my page (the query executed and the results):

```
INSERT INTO users_table (username) VALUES (?)
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>237</font>
</pre>
```

Does anyone know if WAMP, Zend Framework or Doctrine2 come with XDEBUG switched on by default?

EDIT:
Adding this to php.ini seems to remove the HTML formatting?

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump = off
```

Comment: You must have a var_dump() in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks but I really haven't. It's a skeleton structure at present and have just installed Doctrine. It's weird, it echoes out the SQL it's just run and the result set?

Answer (score 1):

I've actually managed to solve this myself and thought I'd post the answer for anyone who stumbles across this.

It seems as part of the Doctrine Entity Manager configuration you can specify a logging method. I'd, without realising, told Doctrine to use `Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger()` - which ofcourse, echo'd the query and results.